# Why my point lamp is going in one direction only?

Tags: light

My point lamp is lighting in one direction and I don't know why. I've tried rotating and it doesn't work.

[image: The point lamp is supposed to light in all directions, right?]

Glad if anyone could help.
Thanks

Edit: I found out the normal map was affecting somehow. anf answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your normal map node's strength is very high. Try setting it below 1.
If you are using the same image texture, it is better to use a bump node and connect it to the height input.
If you have a proper normal map (the purple ones), the image texture node should be set to non-color data and be connected to a normal map node[image: 2 texture map options]'.